# Sequelize creating new model entry when it belongs to a foreign key constraint

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js, foreign-keys

Sorry if the title is not the most easy to understand, im still trying to understand how to explain this. I made a diagram of tables that represent our models (slimmed down version)

As you can see theres three tables where they are connected with a FK. Normally, i could create an entry with the dashboard model and it will create all the associated entries.

So if i do an create on dashboard, it will also create an element and an attirbute and link them together (with FK)

however, one issue I ran into and maybe I am just not understanding the docs, I wish to create a element entry by itself and LINK it back to an existing dashboard row.

I tried different ways, and one way was grabbing the dashboard model and using one of the helper/magic methods (set, create, etc) so for example I would try

```
dashboard.createElement(<payload in here)>
dashboard.setElement(<payload in here)>
dashboard.addElement(<payload in here)>
```

but these fail, the common error is saying dashboard_Id is null and violates the foreign key constraint between dashboard and element or it does that linkage but it wont create the attribute entry and says that attribute_id is null.

Is this possible to do? if I need to add more details please let me know and thank you.

[image]

Comment: Show model defintions and associations